# TigerSwitch 10/100 SMC6724L2 Bandwidth Limiting

Tags: switch

Is is possible to limit bandwidth ports with the managed switch? 
I have: TigerSwitch 10/100 SMC6724L2  and i wish to limit the bandwidth so that:

port one gets 100kbps
port two gets 3mbps

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the manual for that there's only really some 4-level QoS features but nothing as complex as you want.